# trigger infiniteajaxscrolling when there's initially not enough content for scroll bar on page load

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-ias

I'm using *infiniteajaxscrolling*, but my initial ajax call often (depending on screen size) doesn't contain enough content that it shows a scroll bar.

Without scrollbar, there is no scroll event => infinite scrolling never starts?

**How can I let ias load content until there are at least scrollbars visible?**

(except of course, just [coding it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283210/how-can-i-load-enough-images-to-put-a-scroll-bar-on-a-users-page-to-enable-infin) ).

**Is there something like this already implemented in ias I just have to activate?**

I tried just calling ias.next() on a "rendered" event, but that funnily gets to duplicated loading of content. I suppose because somehow a scroll event gets triggered then...

Comment: IAS should automatically load the next page when content is shorter then the viewport. This is actually a feature of IAS. It's kinda strange that's not working for you... which version or IAS are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the newest one, I just cloned it from github last week. Maybe it get's thrown off because I'm using something like a "slide" setup (body is 100% width&height, section make up pages with position:absolute and I smooth scroll to them)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems, the problem is, that the next url gets loaded *AFTER* "rendered" is called. Don't ask me why...

This seems like a pretty painless way to fix it without being to "hackish". Just fast-forwarding loading of the new next url. Doesn't seem to break anything in my testing...

```
ias.on("loaded", $.proxy(function(data, items)
{
    this.nextUrl = this.getNextUrl(data); // fast forward for next() in on.'rendered'
}, ias));

ias.on('rendered',$.proxy(function(items)
{
   if($(CONTAINER).height() <= $(window).height()) // call until scroll bars are shown
   {
      this.next();
   }
}), ias);
```